# Flutter count up number animation

Tags: flutter, animation

I want to make increase number. Number will go from 0 to 90 in 1 second, but I want it to go from 90 to 100 in 2 seconds. So I want the increase in the number to slow down towards the end. How can I do this with flutter animations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use staggered animation. Basically using an Interval you can have an animation running only 90% of the time and then when that animation finishes start another one. You can also add Curves to make it look more realistic.
Read more about it here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations

Comment: Thanks but how can I use two different duration in one animation? begin  fast end slow?